# javascript <= operator not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var MonthsInStartYear = (12 - startMonth) + 1;
var MonthsInEndYear = (12 - endMonth) +1;
var show12Month = MonthsInStartYear + MonthsInEndYear ;

if(MonthsInStartYear < 12) {
  alert("Months in Start Year: " + MonthsInStartYear);

  //check the number of Months for endDate
  if(MonthsInEndYear < 12) {
    alert("Months in Start Year: " + MonthsInEndYear);

    //proceed if total is within 12 months
    if(Number(show12Month) <= 12) {
      alert("hahahaha");
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `alert("hahahaha");` is not executing. What went wrong?

Comment: what is `show12Month`?

Comment: what's your sample scenario? what is the value of `startMonth` and `endMonth`

Comment: those variables are set thru the jquery calender. example startMonth = 5 which means "May"

Comment: What do you see when you put `alert(show12Month)`?

Comment: Can you provide us a scenario where this alert is not working? With the value of startMonth and endMonth .

Comment: There is no need for `Number(show12Month)` since *show12Month* is a number and the `<` operator coerces to number anyway.

Comment: Try ´<11´ instead of ´<= 12´

Maybe there is also something wrong with you ´Number(show12Month)´

Comment: var startMonth=8; var endMonth=9; alert is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `if` statement isn't running then it means that the comparison returns `false`. Check the value in the `else` clause, then try and work out why it's not the value you were expecting.

Add an `else` clause to your final `if` statement, then log the type and value of `show12Month` to the console.

```
if(Number(show12Month) <= 12) {
  alert("hahahaha");
} else {
  console.log(typeof show12Month, show12Month);
}
```

The `<=` operator is definitely working, you're probably just working with a different value from what you're expecting.

Comment: @RobG Not if `startMonth` or `endMonth` coerce to `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Try this its working for me...

```
if(parseInt(show12Month))
{
   var num = parseInt(show12Month);
   if(num <= 12){
      alert("hahahaha");
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason why this would work any better than what the OP already has.

Comment: if your variable 'show12Month' is convert in int or as you can say is number then other condition will work either not

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you're saying, but `Number()` is equivalent to `parseInt()` (in this case).